# how can a web page change my mouse speed?

Tags: firefox, linux-mint, mouse

I usually have many tabs open in Firefox and I haven't been able to find one specific website that causes this because I don't seem to notice it right away.  I'm going to click on something on my desktop and I am lifting up the mouse several times to get across the screen.

It doesn't seem to matter what program I might be using because this happens on all desktops and in Firefox, too.  So I go in my settings and I turn up the mouse speed all the way and it's still not really acceptable.  It doesn't matter if I click on different tabs but when I close the browser, my mouse is way too sensitive, like I'd expect at the max setting.  Then I go back to Control Center and return my mouse speed and acceleration to normal.

When I restart my browser, the mouse remains normal.  So is there something to this before I start wasting my time hunting through my history to discover which website or sites are having this effect?  ...and if it is a specific site and I locate it, what can I change to stop it's effect on my mouse besides not visiting it?

I am using Linux Mint 13 on a box with an AMD Athlon processor and 2gigs of ram.  I never installed another browser because everything works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this sounds like it could be related to two things :
memory or CPU usage.

*you might have too many tabs open and fill the ram to capacity in which case the computer has to resort to virtual memory which tends to slow everything down. in that case closing some tabs (preferably the ones using the most memory) will help

*one or more website might use too much CPU: this is probably caused by hardware acceleration (you can turn it off in advance settings)

You can confirm this by checking the task manager/system monitor next time it happens